# Java Desktop browse() opens %u instead of URI

Tags: java, awt, desktop

Well, the title says it I guess.
When trying to launch the default browser by using the Desktop's browse() function, the browser does open but points to the wrong URI beeing %u

I can't narrow it down to the code, as I haven't changed it.
What I did change was the OS now beeing Ubuntu 11.10 instead of 11.04

And I installed Java 7, but keep using Java 6.

Where does it go wrong? Any Clues?

Comment: *"Any Clues?"*  Do you intend to provide any by posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  Or should we just guess?

Comment: In true 'it works on my box' style an SCCE works just fine on my machine - Ubuntu 11.10. It sounds like the command that is being invoked to launch the browser does not replace the `%u` parameter. I would think that it is an environment issue on the user's desktop

Comment: As I said it wasn't a code issue I didn't think of giving an example. I think I got to dive deeper in the OS. @Petesh do you know where one would set such a parameter? Or from where the issue could arise from?

Comment: It's not a case of you setting the parameter. When you ask to open a URI it invokes `gnome-open <uri>`, You should `strace -v -f -o stracefile <pidofjava>` and then follow the link. This will give you `execve` lines which indicate what commands are being invoked as part of the browse() operation - one of these will probably contain the `%u`, it's the thing calling it that is the problem in this case. It's most likely that the command being invoked for the `browse` command doesn't understand the `%u` syntax (maybe it's an old script - pre gnome3/unity??)

Comment: In the strace I see firefox beeing called and you were right. Firefox is called with %u as parameter, not the actual URI. Didn't see a call for gnome-open, but I guess that Ubuntu developed ther own file hanlder for Unity. Gotta see whats there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm late to the game but I had the same problem, too. Thanks to all the good hints in this question and the comments above I found a config key in gconf-editor:

/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command (and similar)

The command that I found in this key was "firefox %u". Unfortunately, the key was not really documented very well but I noticed that other keys in that area used "%s" for the parameter. So I tried and replaced "%u" by "%s" and - yay! - the darn thing works again.

I'd also like to use this opportunity to thank the guys at Canonical for messing up Unity so thoroughly.